# Length of int Array Roman Numeral to Integer

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, sizeof

The int array decimalSize keeps return a smaller size than expected (2).
Do you know why the int decimalSize array consistently equals 2?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class RomanNumerals {
    public:
        int romanToInt(string s) {

            int sum = 0;
            //int count = 0;
            int size = (sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0])*4);
            int* decNum = new int[size];

            for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
            {
                //count++;
                if (s[i] == 'I')
                {
                    decNum[i] = 1;
                }
                else if (s[i] == 'V')
                {
                    decNum[i] = 5;
                }
                else if (s[i] == 'X')
                {
                    decNum[i] = 10;
                }
                else if (s[i] == 'L')
                {
                    decNum[i] = 50;
                }
                else if (s[i] == 'C')
                {
                    decNum[i] = 100;
                }
                else if (s[i] == 'D')
                {
                    decNum[i] = 500;
                }
                else if (s[i] == 'M')
                {
                    decNum[i] = 1000;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Nothing
                }
            }

            //Attempting to get length of the array via decimalSize
            int decimalSize = (sizeof(decNum)/sizeof(decNum[0]));
            for (int i = 0; i < decimalSize/*count*/; i++)
            {
                if (decNum[i] < decNum[i + 1])
                {
                    sum += decNum[i + 1] - decNum[i];
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    sum += decNum[i];
                }
            }
            return sum;
        }
};
```

I tried using sizeof(decNum)/sizeof(decNum[0]) in the condition in the second for loop at the bottom to get the length of the int array, but did not get the expected result.

Comment: This is because `sizeof(decNum)` does not do what you think it does. `decNum` is an `int *`, so you get a `sizeof(int *)` as a result of this. That's the size of your pointers.

Comment: `int* decNum = new int[size];` Off-topic, but you shouldn't be doing this.  First, you have a memory leak.  Second, forget this and use `std::vector<int> decNum(size);` once you get the `size` part right.

Comment: You should also, perhaps, stop trying to use a search engine to learn C++, and instead get a [good C++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/). You probably wrote "(sizeof(decNum)/sizeof(decNum[0]))" because that was found from searching Google, for doing a part of the task. What you are completely overlooking that you already know the actual size of the array. You wrote it: `int size`. That's the size of the array.

Comment: `sizeof(s)` is also wrong. `sizeof(std::string)` doesn't depend on number of characters inside.

Comment: Use [std::size()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size), [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and forget that C-style arrays exist.

Comment: Forget for now. In another few years my may find yourself writing low-level infrastructure code where old-school C-style arrays and dynamically-allocated memory make sense. But when you use it, hide all of the gory details inside a wrapper class so that the folks using the low-level stuff don't have to care how it works, just like you don't have to care how a `std::vector` or `std::string` works.

Comment: IMHO, a `switch (s[i])` would be a lot easier to read than an `if-else-if` ladder.

Comment: Here are some test cases for you:  `IV, XIX, MCM`.  Try coding the numbers 4, 9 and 1900 into Roman, then send the text to your program.  Roman numbers are not a 1:1 ratio.

Comment: FYI, `sizeof(std::string)` returns the size of the overhead of the `std::string` structure.  Maybe you want `std::string::length()`, which returns the length of the data in the string?